# Is it possible to set width for particular element in wookmark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have following code for initialization of the wookmark

```
$container.find('.item').wookmark({
            itemWidth: 200,
            offset: 38,
            autoResize: true,
            container: $container
        });
```

but I want to make different width for each element depends on attribute in the element, I tried something like

```
...
itemWidth: $(this).attr('imageWidth') ? parseInt($(this).attr(imageWidth)) : 200,
...
```

but **this** doesn't point to an '.item' element, it still points to **$container**

Comment: itemWidth is an option only called once per plugin initialization. You cannot do what you want without extending the plugin. BTW, it won't be an easy task as plugin render elements using unordered list with LIs with position absolute. Maybe an other plugin would be more accurate, e.g gridster.js, even i don't know what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: yes, after reading the documentation, looks like it can't be done with current plugin, I should try something else, but thank you for your comment

Comment: +1 Have you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: that plugin doesn't allow such behavior, so I left items with default width. If you have items with width less than default container width, you can just set some padding inside of frame with standard width.

Answer (score 0):

It should be so.

jQuery.each() iterator and assign different **itemWidth** to each element like this:

```
$('.item').each(function(el) {
  $(el).wookmark({
    itemWidth: $(el).attr('imageWidth')
  });
});
```

Why **this** doesn't refer to item but to $container? Because you call .find() on $container then jQuery returns still $container and you call **.wookmark** on it.

***this*** refers to caller object.

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't seem possible to initialize wookmark for each tile individually.